# Responsive jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Has anyone ever heard of a jQuery slider that is responsive and allows images with different widths?

Thanks

Comment: I've heard of one too.  This is my favorite jQuery slider: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Answer (score 2):

[unoslider.heroku.com](http://unoslider.heroku.com) is the best responsive slider I've seen recently

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider

use your own images

Comment: Revoked until OP clarifies, but isn't it obvious from the context?

Comment: i dont think so.  he said slider using an image, which i meant he wanted to use custom images for the slider handles.  Image Slideshow is not what he said

Comment: Read his comment on the other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879451/responsive-jquery-slider/9879502#comment12600013_9879509. He's interested in image sliders.

Comment: The question was poorly asked.

Comment: that answer was given after I gave mine.  look at the timestamps

Comment: I see the timestamps, but surely you've visited this page since you posted your answer (to respond to these comments and try to seek clarification on what the OP meant, for example)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use the original Slider that comes with JQuery as @cpjolicoeur mentioned above.

You may also try these following:

1. [Responsive Image Gallery with Thumbnail Carousel](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/20/responsive-image-gallery/)
2. [Blueberry](http://marktyrrell.com/labs/blueberry/)

I have used FlexSlider on many responsive websites. But dont know why their site is down. But still you can keep that in your list.

Thanks 
Shajed Evan

Answer (score 0):

One good jQuery plugin that has been around for a while is CarouFredsel (yes, with Fred in the middle). Here is the link:

http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/

They have nice demos for responsive/fluid carousels:

http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/examples/responsive-carousels.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example
http://jsfiddle.net/y2CeN/

Here also in carousel
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php

Both cycle2 using jquery

Answer (score 0):

[Liquid Slider](http://liquidslider.kevinbatdorf.com/) is one that I made. Email me if you have any questions about it. It's pretty powerful, yet simple and to the point. I have been making tutorials for it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You want one of these:

**http://bxslider.com/** [BXSlider](http://bxslider.com/)

**http://unslider.com/**  [UnSlider](http://unslider.com/)